# What is the need to refer the table attribute with the table name while assigning a variable?

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures

In the following stored procedure, I execute a statement:

```
select @subscriptionId := SubscriptionId from subscriptioninfo 
                               where subscriptioninfo.UserId = userId;
```

But if I change the statement to

```
select @subscriptionId := SubscriptionId from subscriptioninfo 
                               where UserId = userId;
```

It returns multiple results though it should return only single result.

What difference does `subscriptioninfo.UserId` create here, when it is obvious that the table named `subscriptioninfo` is being referred.

```
DELIMITER $$

    DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `portaldb`.`update_user_credit_limit`$$

    CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `update_user_credit_limit`(userId int,planId int, newCreditLimit int)
    begin
            if newCreditLimit is not null then 
                /**
                 * Get the subscription id required to update the max credit allocated into the 
                 * planallocation table
                 * The following query creates a local variable @subscriptionId set to the user's
                 * subscription id
                 */
                select @subscriptionId := SubscriptionId from subscriptioninfo where subscriptioninfo.UserId = userId;
                if @subscriptionId is not null then
                    /**
                     * Now update the user's MaxCreditPulseAllocated attribute
                     */
                    update planallocation set MaxCreditPulseAllocated = newCreditLimit where
                        CurrentPlanId = planId and SubscriptionId = @subscriptionId;
                end if;
            end if;
        end$$

    DELIMITER ;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is because your variable name is the same as the table column (variable and column names are case-insensitive in MySQL). When you write the name without a table prefix, it interprets it as the variable, not the column. So `WHERE UserId = userId` is always true because you're comparing the variable to itself, so it returns all columns in the table.

Change your procedure to use a different name for the parameter and you won't have this problem.

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `update_user_credit_limit`(p_userId int,planId int, newCreditLimit int)
begin
    if newCreditLimit is not null then 
        /**
         * Get the subscription id required to update the max credit allocated into the 
         * planallocation table
         * The following query creates a local variable @subscriptionId set to the user's
         * subscription id
         */
        select @subscriptionId := SubscriptionId from subscriptioninfo where UserId = p_userId;
        if @subscriptionId is not null then
            /**
             * Now update the user's MaxCreditPulseAllocated attribute
             */
            update planallocation set MaxCreditPulseAllocated = newCreditLimit where
                CurrentPlanId = planId and SubscriptionId = @subscriptionId;
        end if;
    end if;
end$$
```

BTW, you don't need to do two queries, you can do a single query with a `JOIN`.

```
UPDATE planallocation AS p
JOIN subscriptioninfo AS s ON p.SubscriptionId = s.SubscriptionId
SET p.MaxCreditPulseAllocated = newCreditLimit
WHERE p.CurrentPlanId = planId
AND s.UserId = p_userId
```